# Android Replicate Google Primer Main Screen Transition

Tags: android, transition

How this animation is done: http://zippy.gfycat.com/WeepyBoldAsiandamselfly.mp4?

Considering that everything is in the same activity/fragment, using simple view animations the same effect can be achieved (but i don't know if that's the case). I am guessing that, since Primer came at the same time as the new Lollipop scene transitions, there is a better way. 
Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to replicate this feature by adding the background layout to the header of a `collapsingToolbarLayout` that would 'reveal' when scrolling down.